# Simplify the Complex Fraction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, education, factoring

I am having trouble with the following complex fraction. I have simplified everything for the most part, but I am stuck on the last part and need to know what I have to do next.

$$\frac{\frac{2}{3}+\frac{4}{5}}{\frac{5}{6}-\frac{1}{2}}$$

(I hope this converts over to the way it needs to be displayed.

I have simplified it to
    $\frac{\frac{10}{15}+\frac{12}{15}}{\frac{10}{12}-\frac{6}{12}}$

which equals to
    $\frac{\frac{22}{15}}{\frac{4}{12}}$

simplified to

$\frac{4}{12}×\frac{15}{22}$

At this point do I cross multiply and then add the two results? I can't figure out what to do next. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get $\frac{12*22}{15*4} = \frac{22}{5}$.

Comment: So what your saying to do next is to reduce the 4/12 to 1/3, and then knock out the 15 and the 3 to 5 and 1?

Comment: @SprJD7903 yep just that.

Answer (score 1):

**(5/6)-(1/2)** <- for this one you could just multiply the numerator and denominator of the second fraction ***by 3*** instead of ***6*** and it'll be **(5/6)-(3/6)**

Then you'll get **(22/15)/(2/6)** , Then, to divide two fractions you **take the second one and flip it then multiply**. So, this **(22/15)/(2/6)** becomes this **(22/15)*(6/2)**

To make your life easier **see if you can simplify before multiplying**. Well, in this case we certainly can. **22** is divisible by **2** and **2** is divisible by **2**. Also, **6** is divisible by **3** and **15** is divisible by **3**. After simplifying it'll be **(11/5)*(2/1)** at this point there isn't anymore simplification you can make so the answer is:

**22/5**

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is $22/5$:
$$
\frac{\frac{2}{3}+\frac{4}{5}}{\frac{5}{6}-\frac{1}{2}}=
\frac{\frac{10+12}{15}}{\frac{5-3}{6}}=
\frac{\frac{22}{15}}{\frac{2}{6}}=
\frac{\frac{22}{15}}{\frac{1}{3}}=
\frac{22}{15}\cdot \frac{3}{1}=\frac{22}{5}.
$$